# Fluent NHibernate mapping protected properties: could not resolve property: BookingNumber of: B

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

Assume the following classes:

```
public class A
{
  public virtual ind Id { get; set; }
  public virtual int Number { get; protected set; }
}

public class B : A
{
  public virtual string SomeValue { get; set; }

  public virtual int BookingNumber
  {
    get { return Number; }
    set { Number = value; }
  }
}

public class C : A
{
  public virtual string SomeOtherValue { get; set; }

  public virtual int AccountNumber
  {
    get { return Number; }
    set { Number = value; }
  }
}
```

As you can see I want to expose the property Number under different names.

Now I want to map A, B, C.

```
public class AMap : ClassMap<A>
{
  public AMap()
  {
    Id(x => x.Id);
    Map(x => x.Number);
  }
}

public class BMap : SubclassMap<B>
{
  public BMap()
  {
    Map(x => x.SomeValue);
  }
}

public class CMap : SubclassMap<C>
{
  public CMap()
  {
    Map(x => x.SomeOtherValue);
  }
}
```

With this mapping I can save stuff to the database.

However when I query B or C:

```
Session.QueryOver<B>().Where(x => x.BookingNumber).List();
```

I receive the error `could not resolve property: BookingNumber of: B`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This design sounds horrible... Why do you need to do it like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is wrong? To build query on unmapped properties.

> *(wrapping base properties in derrived classes with DIFFERENT names is at least strange)*, 
>   If this approach is really needed because some upper layers need diffrent
>   names for the same property... then, well, ok. But, NHibernate must be
>   provided with different set of information.

Think about your query, as self descriptive information, containing enough to be converted to SQL statement.

So if you use `QueryOver<B>.Where(x => x.BookingNumber == 1)...`. the information is (when parsing lambda expressions):

1. Work with C# object `B`,
2. find its property `BookingNumber`,
3. find its mapped representation: column name `BookingNumberColumn`,
4. take the value: `1` and
5. built a query `WHERE BookingNumberColumn = 1`

In this case, the step number 3 fails. No column is mapped to `BookingNumber`...

Solution is, at least on Data (NHibernate) layer, apply filter based on a base class `A` mapping

```
Session
  .QueryOver<B>()
  .Where(x => x.Number == 1) // use the A.Number MAPPED property
  .List<B>();
```

BUT, based on my experience, what we are mostly doing, is the conversion of differences in  persistance (different id column name, different code column) and map them to the C# base class or interface with common, simplified structure.

More here: [16. QueryOver Queries](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#queryqueryover)